# The word order and prepositions in an example

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-order

Background to the sentence: a system activates itself after temperature has been deviated for [X] seconds.

Now I want to describe what X does and I just cannot figure it out. My best attempts are:

> The value X specifies the time period for which the temperature has to
>   be deviated.
>
> The value X specifies the time period during which the temperature has to be
>   deviated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say neither works, because *deviate* should be [intransitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deviate#Verb). You cannot deviate temperature. Or really anything. It can only deviate all by itself. What you can do is *change* it, or *alter* it, or *influence* it, or *meddle with* it, or what have you. But not deviate it.

> X specifies the number of seconds for which the temperature has deviated from the norm.

With "the time period", I'd probably go with an *in*, but as you can see I don't use "the time period" in the first place. That's because then it's not clear *what* the time period is specified *in* (nanoseconds? weeks? centuries?). So I replace it with the actual unit, killing two birds with one stone. The temperature has deviated for X seconds.

Likewise, while it's possible to just end the sentence after the "deviated", it sounds more natural when you specify what it deviated *from*. I just went with a boilerplate "the norm" here, but I suppose you can be more specific and replace it with the actual number. Of course if you have done that in a preceding sentence, you can omit it here.